# Can I have a model called "Transaction" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We'd like to have a model called "Transaction" that corresponds to our "transactions" table for our database in Rails, but this will collide with existing ActiveRecord transactions functionality.

Aside from coming up with a different name for the Transaction model (which I'd like to not do), is there anything else I can do to support the model?

Comment: [This post](http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words) seems to suggest that `Transaction` is a reserved word. A quick test shows you can use it as a model name but from experience, particularly in models, you can find yourself far down a road before the error becomes apparent and walking back can be a challenge. How about appending the name of your app to the model name so that it becomes AppTransaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say no. I tried to create a model named `Transaction` and I got an Active Record error when I tried to do some associations with it.

> You tried to define an association named transaction on the model
>   Item, but this will conflict with a method transaction already defined
>   by Active Record. Please choose a different association name.

I landed on this Stack Overflow question wondering the same thing but based on my experience now I wouldn't recommend it – it looks like `Transaction` is probably a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain, but I think it ought to be fine. Generally Rails is pretty proactive about telling you when you're trying to use a name that'll conflict, so why not try it out and see what happens?

If the table name (as opposed to the model name) turns out to be an issue, you can always use `self.table_name = "some_other_table_name"` in your model (as described in [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions)) to give it the name of another table to use.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can, I have used that name for model and works ok.

If you are concerned about the `transactions` on Rails, they are methods for the ActiveRecord::Transactions class.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html