# Comparing time for nested associations

Tags: ruby, comparison, nested-includes

I'm in the process of building an application that'll accept a specific date from a user and which will then provide a list of events that have occurred prior to that date. While my code works if I'm looking for a specific value, I'm unable to perform a search when a particular date is passed in. Essentially i'd like to view all of the children elements that occurred previous to that particular date.

```
My Investments models is this: 

    class Investment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transactions

  def count
    final_quanity = 0
    self.transactions.each do |transaction|
      final_quanity+= transaction.quantity
    end
    final_quanity
  end

  def average_price
    total_spent = 0
    self.transactions.each do |transaction|
      total_spent += transaction.price
    end
    total_spent
  end
end
```

My transactions model is this:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :investment


end
```

Investment controller

```
class InvestmentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:date]

      # @investments = Investment.includes(:transactions).where(transactions: {quantity:10})
      @investments = Investment.includes(:transactions).where("date > ?", params[:date])
    else
      @investments = Investment.all
    end
    render json: @investments
  end

end
```

I'd like to only return the specific transactions that occurred before the date entered, by I'm having difficulty returning with a conditional. As you can see from the blocked out code, I'm able to successfully return entries that have a specific value. What's the appropriate way to complete the active record query with a conditional?

What's strange is that the following works:

```
@transactions = Transaction.where("date < ?", date)
```

While this doesn't:

```
  @investments = Investment.includes(:transactions).where("date > ?", date)
```

Instead I get an error message that these's no such column as "date".

Essentially what's the best way to perform this action:

```
  @investments = Investment.includes(:transactions).where( :transactions => {:price => 100})
```

except determining if a value is greater than or less than instead of just matching.

Comment: Format code by indenting with four spaces, or using the `{}` button to do that automatically.

Comment: What does "compare two different dates" mean in the context of this `index` action?

Comment: Not sure exactly what's not working here. Can you show an example like "I want to do _this_ but get _this_ error"

Comment: Avoid using naming model as `Transaction` as it is reserved for upgraded rails, perhaps works for `rails-3` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060415/10522579